# javascript - why is declared function invoked at runtime

Tags: javascript, function

The mere declaration of a function to an object leads to its invocation

```js
var a  = {};
a.xyz = new function() { 
    alert("dosomething");
}
```

I would expect, that the declared function `a.xyz` only gets invoked when I call it:

```
a.xyz();
```

What is wrong with my assumption?

Comment: Remove new in your code

Comment: +1 for asking this. Not because I don't know the answer but because I didn't know that javascript allows anonymous constructors. This may end up being a new design pattern I end up using a lot. Kind of like IIFE. IIAC (Immediately Invoked Anonymous Constructor)?

Comment: new function(){} is not the same as funtion(){}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove new and everything will be fine:

```
var a  = {};
a.xyz = function() { 
    alert("dosomething");
}
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/vnj8pzm1/

**EDIT:** More about IIFE - [Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/)

Comment: would be nice if you argue why ;)

Comment: @iceless That is incorrect, see my comments http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/kzhg9ggu/

Comment: I guess I understood it right. I deleted my comment :)

Answer (score 3):

When you put `new` in front of your function definition, your function is being called as a constructor immediately.

As iceless mentioned, you should not have `new` in front of your function defintion. However, what iceless mentioned in the comment is incorrect

> new function() {} or new function() {}(); will invoke the function just like function() {}(); or (function() {}());

`new function() {}` will create a new instance of an anonymous type, so in your code `a.xyz` is an object

if you change it to just `function(){}()` it would execute the function immediately and return nothing. See http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/kzhg9ggu/

Answer (score 3):

#### In short:

The new operator create an instance of the object with new, and that's why is executed right after the declaration.

#### In not so short

```
xyz= function(){};
```

Places a reference to an anonymous function into xyz and points to a function.

```
xyz= new function(){};
```

Places a reference to a newly constructed instance of an anonymous constructor function, so it will points to an object. Try `typeof new function(){}` and you will get object.

When the code `new function(){alert('foo');}` is executed, the following things happen:

1. A new object is created
2. The constructor function is called with the specified arguments and this bound to the newly created object. If no argument list is specified, function() is called without arguments.
3. The object returned by the constructor function becomes the result of the whole new expression. If the constructor function doesn't explicitly return an object, the object created in step 1 is used instead.